# Por qué la página 2 me lista los mismos elementos de la página 1

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Me acaban de pasar una página wordpress para administrarla, pero no logro encontrar el error en el php que hace que al cargar un listado de 40 elementos, me muestre 20 en la primera página y en la segunda en lugar de los 21 al 40, me vuelve a mostrar los del 1 al 20.

El código es el siguiente:

```
function generarRed($red, $icono)
{

    if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $red)[0] != "") 
    {
        $valor = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $red)[0];

        if (strpos($valor, 'http') !== false || strpos($valor, 'https') !== false) 
        {
            $regreso = '<a target="_blank" href="' . $valor . '"><i class="fa ' . $icono . '"></i></a>';

        } else {

           $regreso = '<a target="_blank" href="http://' . $valor . '"><i class="fa ' . $icono . '"></i></a>';
        }

      return $regreso;

    } else {

     return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Ese es el código que debería mostrar la lista de posts? No veo ningún bucle en él...

Comment: Mirando ese código no veo absolutamente ni un solo elemento que me dé una pista de cómo se generan los resultados... Resulta difícil poder ayudarte. ¿Dónde está el parámetro que indica el número de página? ¿Dónde está el bucle con los elementos del listado?

Comment: Ese código solamente trae el link de un post envolviendo una etiqueta `i`. Vamos a necesitar ver el bucle que está en las otras plantillas. Pregunta: si vas a la vista por categoría, la segunda página tiene el mismo comportamiento?

Comment: Este es el código completo:

Comment: Subo esta página con el código completo:

(http://www.freelince.com/codigo_completo.html)

por favor disculplen, estoy muy básico en php. Agradezco enormemente cualquier ayuda